# Possible to Spoof Cross Domain Cookie?

Tags: security, cookies, cross-domain, session-cookies, spoofing

Working with a third party who own a domain e.g. abc.com

We are building a web app hosted on a different domain. e.g. xyz.com

The third party are responsible for authentication.
Their users will make requests to xyz.com, proxied through abc.com.

They have asked us to authorise the request by:

Checking for the existence of a session cookie from their domain - abc.com (we can't decode the cookie, to validate it, so the value could be anything.)

When the request is forwarded to us, they will also provide the user name

Is this secure?

Are their ways a hacker could spoof a cookie from a abc.com, and go direct to xyz.com?

Comment: Have you or the third party company considered using oauth2?